# Update with inner join (SQL Server to Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which works fine in MS SQL Server, but when I run it on Oracle I get the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

The query is:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET ROW1 = dat.ROW1,
    ROW2 = dat.ROW2,
    ROW3 = dat.ROW3
FROM    TABLE1  AS dest
INNER JOIN  TABLE2  AS dat ON dest.ROW4 = dat.ROW4 AND dest.ROW5 = dat.ROW5 AND dest.ROW6 = dat.ROW6
WHERE   dest.ROW4 = dat.ROW4
        AND dest.ROW5 = dat.ROW5
        AND dest.ROW6 = dat.ROW6
```

Comment: `ROW!` this should be `ROW1`

Comment: sorry. My mistake. It did not work when I wrote it down properly.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - the question clearly states that the OP has a query which runs on MS SQL Server that they want to run on Oracle too. So why is the tagging wrong?

Comment: 오타가 아니야. 제대로 작성해도 동작하지 않았어.

Comment: Retracted vote. Sorry, I obviously didn't read the question too well.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support ANSI 92 joins in UPDATE (or DELETE) statements which is a real shame; it would be neat if it did. The question I have linked to shows several workarounds to this problem.